# Match part of string enclosed by delimiters using regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match a a part of a string with delimiters. The strings I would like to retrive are currency symbols.

Strings look like:

```
0.040-aa-¥-bb-234,5.4
234,5.4-aa-CN¥-bb-blahblahb
-aa-$-bb-sdfsefblah3949
34blah-aa-$-bb-
and so on.
```

This should be extracted into:

```
¥
CN¥
$
$
```

So essentially, I will have a string made up of any amount of characters, with currency symbols. The currency symbol will always have -aa- at the front and -bb- at the back. I would like to retrive what's between those 2 delimiters.

Currently, I have came up with this expression: `-aa-[^\]]+-bb-`, however, it includes the -aa- and -bb-. How do I exclude those parts?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match('/(?<=-aa-)[^-]*(?=-bb-)/', $string, $matches)
```

gives you the currency symbol as the entire match result.

`(?<=...)` and `(?=...)` are [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), meaning they check for the presence of the enclosed regexes before or after the current position without making them a part of the overall match.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that this works only because the delimiters are of a fixed length. PHP doesn't support infinite repetition inside lookbehind assertions (for example, .NET does), but this isn't a problem in your case.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the specific part of the expression, use a capturing group, eg

```
if (preg_match('/-aa-(.+?)-bb-/', $string, $matches) == 1) {
    $symbol = $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to do this without a subpattern and then access it via $matches[0]?